# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error in HMVC Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

**When Page loads in my console it shows this error**

> Font from origin 'http://example.com' has been blocked from loading by
>   Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin
>   'http://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

**and when i call ajax function. it show this error**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://example.com/index.php/home/getCity?city=d. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Which ajax functions are in home controller. But i'm in another controller. may be I think it was problem. how can i solve this ?

Comment: See this : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Cross-Origin Resource in Codeignitor you have to include this line in controller right after start of `<?php` tag

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: Where view page or controller ?

Comment: in your url http://example.com/index.php/home/getCity?city=d  i can see that home is your controller So include this line in contorller

Comment: Yes its working. And for ajax function we need to add  crossDomain: true,

Comment: hi there, in my case is like this. "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mysitenotwork.com/assets/css/prism.css. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access."
how to solve it.?

Comment: use same line header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); right after your controller <?php tag

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
class Myclass extends CI_Controller {

}
```

This works perfectly fine in codeigniter